# List elements within a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I generated a list of data from a CSV file. It came out as format as a list within a list:

```
Wind = [['284'], ['305'], ['335'], ['331'], ['318'], ['303'], ['294'], ['321'], ['324'], ['343']]
```

I need to list as regular list. So here is my attempt at solving this problem:

```
i = 0
for ii in Wind:
    Wind[i] = Wind[i][i]
    i += 1
    return Wind
```

My output is:

```
return Wind
   ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to flatten the list, which can be done in python using a list comprehension (essentially a shorter, faster, version of a for loop).

```
Wind = [x for y in Wind for x in y]
```

The equivalent code using nested `for` loops would be:

```
newWind = []
for y in Wind:
    for x in y:
        newWind.append(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, using itertools:

```
import itertools
newWind = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(Wind))
```

and another one using numpy:

```
import numpy
newWind = numpy.array(Wind).transpose()[0].tolist()
```

and one using a list comprehension that assumes there will always be only one element in the inner lists:

```
newWind = [x[0] for x in Wind]
```

and one using map making the same assumption:

```
newWind = map(lambda x:x[0], Wind)
```

take your pick!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error results because you are trying to execute a return statement when you aren't in a function.  If you just want to print the contents of Wind, use `print(Wind)` instead of `return Wind`

Comment: He doesn't want to print the list, he wants it to not be 2D.

Comment: Right, I realize you answered the question better but I was just pointing out that simple syntax error. I can't post comments yet or I would have done that of course

Comment: Apologies, I thought anyone could comment on a question.

Comment: Yeah requires 50 rep I think for some reason haha

Comment: Thanks. Yes, definitely the initial problem.